# Отношение максимальных элементов строки матрицы с заданными номерами

Tags: c

Как найти отношение максимальных элементов строк матрицы? Ниже есть код. Программа выводит максимальные элементы требуемых строк.

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>
char STR[25];
int main()
{
    int n=4,m=4;
    int i,j,max,k;
    int a[n][m];
    int num=1;
    int q;
    CharToOem("Программа вычисляет отношение максимальных элементов двух строк матрицы с заданными номерами.\n",STR);
    puts(STR);
    CharToOem("Матрица имеет вид: \n",STR);
    puts(STR);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {
    for (j=0; j<m; j++)  
    {
    a[i][j]=rand()%10;
    printf("%4d", a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }       
    CharToOem("Введите номер строки q: \n",STR);
    puts(STR);                        
    scanf("%d",&q);  
    for (i=q; i<q+1; i++)
    {                          
    max = 0;
    for (j=1; j<m; j++)
    {
    if (a[i][j] > a[i][max])
    max = j;
    } 
     printf("\n"); 
    printf("Max.element %d: ",num);        
    printf("%d\n",a[i][max]);
    printf("\n");

    CharToOem("Введите номер строки q: \n",STR);
    puts(STR);                        
    scanf("%d",&q);  
    for (i=q; i<q+1; i++)
    {                          
    max = 0;
    for (j=1; j<m; j++)
    {
    if (a[i][j] > a[i][max])
    max = j;
    } 
    printf("\n"); 
    printf("Max.element %d: ",num);        
    printf("%d\n",a[i][max]);



    }
    getch();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо завести переменную и в нее сложить

До цикла по i

```
pr=1;
```

После того как нашли максимум

```
If (max!=0){ pr=max/pr;}
```